# Creating two set of child name server for two diff servers with same domain name

Tags: vps, nameserver

I have two servers, both having different ips. I am using my custom name server

ns1.domain.com -> server 1 ip
ns2.domain.com -> server 1 ip

Now i had purchased a new vps having ip 43.XX.XX.XX, now i am tried creating another name servers

ns3.domain.com -> server 2 ip
ns4.domain.com -> server 2 ip

but since last 3 days it is not give desired ping result and my website not redirecting to my vps

So my question is it possible to create 2 set of child name servers  for same domain for  two diff ip and server?

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, your original setup used two different names for the same ip? While that is fine, it also looks like you attempt to use these diffent names (which refer to the same physical server) probably as only registered/authoritative name servers for a domain. - This would be bad if you really did that; and maybe your curretn action is intended to relieve that. NS entries of public DNS zones very strongly should be reachable via independent uplinks (and this is mostly understood as: have ip addresses from different class C networks).

Nonetheless, to answer your questions: You can have "arbitrarily many" NS entries in each DNS zone, and each host name may resolve to arbitrarily many ip addresses. However, the various name servers thus found authoritative for a zone should agree on the data they return. So, did you test the following (wherin I assume that the command `ping 43.xx.xx.xx` succeeds but `ping ns3.domain.com` does not):

1. Issue

   `host -t ns domain.com`

   Are the names returned your two or four nsX.domain.com servers? Or are they name servers of your registrar/provider?
2. For each name server `nsX.whatever.com` from step 1 issue

   `host -t ns domain.com nsX.whatever.com`

   Are the results identical?
3. For each name server `nsX.whatever.com` from step 1 issue

   `host -t A ns3.domain.com nsX.whatever.com`

   Do they all return your new `43.xx.xx.xx` ip?
4. In case of differnig results in steps 2 or 3, issue

   `host -t SOA domain.com nsX.whatever.com`

   Do they all return the same info (especially, serial number)?
5. Finally, also check the name server entries published in

   `whois domain.com`

I guess most of the possible problems you have should be detectable with the above steps.

Comment: Although i am not able to understand your answer completely, but there are two diff server that i am targeting, as 2 ns record are consider as good so i ahve ns1 and ns2.  then what if i want to create 2 more ns records for a diff ip than ns1 and ns2, but not sure it is possible/ recommended or not

Comment: @Omprks As I said (or tried to say), you can have as many `NS` records in your zone as you like. And each of the domain names you use (as `NS` entry or otherwise) can have many `A` (or nowadays `AAAA`) records associted to it. However, apart from "intrinsic" correctness (i.e,. all listed name servers are **reachable** and consider themselves **authoritative** for the zone) you should also verify proper delegation (i.e., do the name servers for the `com` zone list at least **some** of your name servers as `NS` entries for the domains they serve; and do they provide **glue records** if needed?)

Comment: Could you perform at least *some* of the tests I suggested? OR are you willing to drop anonymization and say what `domain.com` (or even ultimately `www.thesameorpossiblyanotherdomain.com`) really is, so I could perform the tests for you?

Comment: . . . i did whois check i did ping check but SOA and other things. But i really greatful to you for quick responses and help.

Comment: Alternatively you can check my two ns records ns1.innctech.in and ns3.innctech.in both are pointing to diff ips and ns1 is working but ns3 is not

Comment: @Omprks Alright, contrary to what I interpreted into your question, `ns1.innctech.in` and `ns2.innctech.in` have totally different ip addresses - that's great. It seems that you simply forgot to add the required DNS resource records at your name servers. Presumably `ns1` acts as a master and `ns2` automatically syncs with it (after at most one day), so a change at `ns1` suffices. Add `@ NS ns3.innctech.in.` and `ns3 A 43.xx.xx.xx` to the zone file; don't forget to update the serial number in the SOA record; reload. You may want to add the `A` only first and check reachability.

Comment: I have updated A record for ns1 and ns2 as ip of server, let see what happen after propagation.

Comment: Temporarily I got 103.21.59.25 for `ns3`, but no more. Especially, ns1 and ns2 do not have that data, so if any of those is your master, there is nothing that will propagate; it seems I pulled and cached that from 8.8.8.8 somehow. Even I am beginning to get confused, for example your nservers have very different SOA reords with different responsible mailbox names and all have serial numbers dating back to 2014. I suggest you *thoroughly* revisit your DNS setup. How and on which server do you edit your zone data?